# Hierarchically printing "incollection" items beneath their "collection"?

Tags: biblatex, sorting

I have a Bib(La)TeX database where every entry is either a book/collection, or an `incollection` item. I would like to generate a reading list from this database, and it is convenient if all the items from the same book/collection can be gathered together, and listed immediately after the entry for the collection.

Is there a way to automate this using BibLaTeX?

For example, in the example bib database included below, there is one `@book` and one `@proceedings`, and 5 `@incollections`. I would like the output to be listed like

```
  Global analysis. Papers in honor of K. Kodaira. ....
    Atiyah, M. F., "The signature of fibre-bundles" ...
    Griffiths, P. A., "Hermitian differential geometry, Chern classes, and positive vector bundles" ...
    Hirzebruch, F., "The signature of ramified coverings" ...

  Proceedings of the 7th Congress (7ECM) held in Berlin, July 18--22, 2016 ...
    Baranov, A. and Belov, Y., "Spectral synthesis in Hilbert spaces of entire functions"...
    Savare, G., "Diffusion, optimal transport and Ricci curvature"...
```

For the time being, the precise formatting of the entries don't matter too much to me, nor is the sorting (of the collections, or of articles within a collection). **If I can get a pointer on how to list `incollections` "hierarchically" as shown, I can probably fix the rest myself.**

Fundamentally, I guess the question (though maybe I am thinking about this wrong) is whether I can "sort" by

1. First sorting all the books/collections
2. For each book/collection, taking all the items that are in that collection, sorting them, and inserting this list of entries immediately after the entry for the book/collection.

Example `bib` file:

```
@book {MR0253344,
     TITLE = {Global analysis. {P}apers in honor of {K}. {K}odaira.},
    EDITOR = {Spencer, D. C. and Iyanaga, S.},
 PUBLISHER = {University of Tokyo Press, Tokyo; Princeton University Press,
              Princeton,
 N.J., },
      YEAR = {1969},
     PAGES = {v+414 pp. (1 plate)},
   MRCLASS = {57.00},
  MRNUMBER = {253344},
}

@incollection {MR0254864,
    AUTHOR = {Atiyah, M. F.},
     TITLE = {The signature of fibre-bundles.},
 BOOKTITLE = {Global {A}nalysis ({P}apers in {H}onor of {K}. {K}odaira)},
     PAGES = {73--84},
 PUBLISHER = {, },
      YEAR = {1969},
   MRCLASS = {57.30},
  MRNUMBER = {254864},
MRREVIEWER = {K.\ H.\ Mayer},
}

@incollection {MR0258060,
    AUTHOR = {Hirzebruch, F.},
     TITLE = {The signature of ramified coverings.},
 BOOKTITLE = {Global {A}nalysis ({P}apers in {H}onor of {K}. {K}odaira)},
     PAGES = {253--265},
 PUBLISHER = {, },
      YEAR = {1969},
   MRCLASS = {57.47},
  MRNUMBER = {258060},
MRREVIEWER = {M.\ F.\ Atiyah},
}

@incollection {MR0258070,
    AUTHOR = {Griffiths, Phillip A.},
     TITLE = {Hermitian differential geometry, {C}hern classes, and positive
              vector
 bundles.},
 BOOKTITLE = {Global {A}nalysis ({P}apers in {H}onor of {K}. {K}odaira)},
     PAGES = {185--251},
 PUBLISHER = {, },
      YEAR = {1969},
   MRCLASS = {57.60 (53.00)},
  MRNUMBER = {258070},
MRREVIEWER = {R.\ L. E. Schwarzenberger},
}

@proceedings {MR3887693,
     TITLE = {European {C}ongress of {M}athematics},
 BOOKTITLE = {Proceedings of the 7th {C}ongress (7{ECM}) held in {B}erlin,
              {J}uly 18--22, 2016},
    EDITOR = {Mehrmann, Volker and Skutella, Martin},
 PUBLISHER = {European Mathematical Society (EMS), Z\"{u}rich},
      YEAR = {2018},
     PAGES = {x+889},
      ISBN = {978-3-03719-176-7},
   MRCLASS = {00B20},
  MRNUMBER = {3887693},
}

@incollection {MR3887767,
    AUTHOR = {Baranov, Anton and Belov, Yurii},
     TITLE = {Spectral synthesis in {H}ilbert spaces of entire functions},
 BOOKTITLE = {European {C}ongress of {M}athematics},
     PAGES = {203--218},
 PUBLISHER = {Eur. Math. Soc., Z\"{u}rich},
      YEAR = {2018},
      ISBN = {978-3-03719-176-7},
   MRCLASS = {30D15 (47A10)},
  MRNUMBER = {3887767},
MRREVIEWER = {Lev\ Sergeevich\ Maergoiz},
}

@incollection {MR3887773,
    AUTHOR = {Savar\'{e}, Giuseppe},
     TITLE = {Diffusion, optimal transport and {R}icci curvature},
 BOOKTITLE = {European {C}ongress of {M}athematics},
     PAGES = {311--331},
 PUBLISHER = {Eur. Math. Soc., Z\"{u}rich},
      YEAR = {2018},
      ISBN = {978-3-03719-176-7},
   MRCLASS = {58J65 (53C21)},
  MRNUMBER = {3887773},
}
```

If it makes a difference: I am happy to edit the `bib` database to include either `crossref` or `xref` keys, in place or or in addition to `booktitle`.